# Instruction set - Decode opcode

Tags: opcode, instruction-set

I'm trying to understand how the **/d** affects the opcode.

Example:
FF **/6**      PUSH r/m16     M     Valid     Valid     Push r/m16.

How meaning is expressed?

Can anyone give me an example of the difference?

Thanks!

Comment: The information you have given is insufficient. Where does this opcode comes into play? Is it in a real hardware or in a simulator?

Comment: in real hardware, x86 cpu.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually many instructions using `FF` as opcode:

```
INC     rm16                                    FF /0
INC     rm32                                    FF /0
INC     rm64                                    FF /0
DEC     rm16                                    FF /1
DEC     rm32                                    FF /1
DEC     rm64                                    FF /1
CALL    rm16                                    FF /2
CALL    rm32                                    FF /2
CALL    rm64                                    FF /2
CALL FAR        mem16:16                        FF /3
CALL FAR        mem16:32                        FF /3
JMP     rm16                                    FF /4
JMP     rm32                                    FF /4
JMP     rm64                                    FF /4
JMP FAR mem16:16                                FF /5
JMP FAR mem16:32                                FF /5
PUSH    rm16                                    FF /6
PUSH    rm32                                    FF /6
PUSH    rm64                                    FF /6
```

As you may see, the */d* part is a 3 bit sequence held in the byte following the opcode (the so called ModR/M byte), which help discriminate the correct instruction.

From the Intel reference documentation:

> Many instructions that refer to an operand in memory have an addressing-form spec-
>   ifier byte (called the ModR/M byte) following the primary opcode. The ModR/M byte
>   contains three fields of information:
>
> • The mod field combines with the r/m field to form 32 possible values: eight
>      registers and 24 addressing modes.
>
> • The reg/opcode field specifies either a register number or three more bits of
>      opcode information. The purpose of the reg/opcode field is specified in the
>     primary opcode.
>
> • The r/m field can specify a register as an operand or it can be combined with the
>      mod field to encode an addressing mode. Sometimes, certain combinations of
>     the mod field and the r/m field is used to express opcode information for some
>    instructions.

So that */d* value is actually extracted from the *reg/opcode* field. When the CPU loads up the first opcode, it knows that it should read an additional byte following it, and read that field in order to complete the instruction.